# Is there a way to remove a name from a Docker container?

Tags: docker

We found that running `docker rm myprocess` takes quite a bit of time, much longer than `docker run` takes to start a fresh copy.

Is there a way we can make a container give up its name, so that we can first free up the name to be able to `docker run` again, and then do the time-consuming cleanup of the old container later?

That would make the stop/start cycle when updating to newer versions of the underlying image faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [rename a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rename/) that already exists, or you could deploy with a new name then rename it afterwards:

```
docker rename myprocess myprocess-old
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been multiple reports of that problem.
[Issue 16281](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16281) mentions (about the devicemapper or dm):

> Switching the `dm.basesize` to 10GB seems to be fixing the issue so far, maybe it would be worth reverting the default to 10GB instead of 100GB or even specify this option at the creation of the container as requested in [issue 14678](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14678)

See the [docker daemon storage driver options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#storage-driver-options):

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=10G
```

Switching to thinpool can help too:

```
docker daemon --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/thin-pool
```

Comment: Ah, making the `rm` faster would of course also be a good solution. Since my containers are supposed to be stateless, is there a way to tell Docker that the root file system is read-only (and would that speed up things)?

Comment: @Thilo soon: http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/12/making-docker-images-write-only-in-production/

Comment: @Thilo in the meantime, could you check if those `docker daemon` options would improve the speed of `docker rm`?